# knockout issue with deleting from observable array

Tags: function, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I'm having data binding a knockout function to my html.

Following is the view model:

```
  var DonutViewModel = function () {
        this.donuts = ko.observableArray();
        //donutData = JSON.parse(donutData);
        var items = $.map(donutData, function (data) { return new Donut(data) });
        this.donuts(items);
        this.deletedonut = function (item) {
            this.donuts.remove(item);
        }
    }
   var viewModel;
   $(document).ready(function () {
      viewModel = new DonutViewModel();
      ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
   });
```

following is the html:

```
 <tr>
    <td><input id="txtdonutid" type="text" data-bind="value:id"/></td>
    <td><input id="txtdonuttype" type="text" data-bind="value:type"/></td>
    <td><input id="txtdonutname" type="text" data-bind="value:dname"/></td>
    <td><input id="txtppu" type="text" data-bind="value:ppu"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Delete Donut" data-bind="click: function() {$parent.deletedonut($data)}"/></td>
</tr>
```

Notice how I have data-bound the delete function and THIS WORKS!. but if I do the following:

```
  <td><input type="button" value="Delete Donut" data-bind="click: {$parent.deletedonut($data)}"/></td>
```

well, this doesn't work. The delete function doesn't even get hit.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Writing `data-bind="click: function() {$parent.deletedonut($data)}"` is the correct syntax. Why do you want to write `data-bind="click: {$parent.deletedonut($data)}"`?

Comment: well, if you look at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html, the binding syntax for click event is data-bind="click: myfunction". this doesn't say that you have to use function() in the click binding. So why is it different?

Comment: But if you want to additonal parameter you need that syntax. See the data-bind="click: {$parent.deletedonut($data)}" senction. However in your case the following should work: `data-bind="click: $parent.deletedonut"`

Comment: data-bind="click: $parent.deletedonut" - this worked, thanks!

Comment: BTW what you mean is that if I want additional parameters than the default data, i should use the above syntax is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to the `function() ...` syntax in your click binding if you want to pass additional parameter to your handler beside the `$data.` (see the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html): Accessing the event object, or passing more parameters section)

But if your only parameter is `$data` then KO will automatically pass that in so you can just write:

```
<input type="button" value="Delete Donut" 
                     data-bind="click: $parent.deletedonut"/>
```

Note: there is no need for the `{}` and you also don't need arguments as well `($data)` because you are passing the `$parent.deletedonut` as the reference to that handler function.

But in itself this won't work in your case because you are using `this` in your handler to access your view model.

You have two options:

You can use `bind`: `data-bind="click: $parent.deletedonut.bind($parent)"`  in this case you don't need to change your handler.

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9tpgd/.)

Or you can store a reference of the `this` in a variable like `self` and use that in your handler instead of the `this`.

So change your handler to:

```
var self = this; 
this.deletedonut = function (item) {
    self.donuts.remove(item);
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/CFCes/)

Comment: unfortunately, <input type="button" value="Delete Donut" 
                     data-bind="click: $parent.deletedonut"/> this is not working for me :( I tried creating a fiddle but it's broken http://jsfiddle.net/bxfXd/2269/

Comment: thanks a lot! it makes sense. Using 'this' inside the delete/add function set the reference to the topping object, not the donut. Thanks for explaining this.